# Text box color needs to be changed whenever it is disabled using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jsp

In my HTML I have 2 combo boxes and one text box. When these 3 are disabled then text box's background color is not the same as the combo boxes'. I've tried using following CSS.

```
<head>
  <style>
     input:enabled
     {
       background:#ffff00;
     }
     input:disabled
     {
       background:#dddddd;
     }
   </style>
</head>
```

Answer (score 2):

if you are using `<select>` elements, you need select in each CSS selector too:

```
input:enabled, select:enabled
{
background:#ffff00;
}
input:disabled, select:disabled
{
background:#dddddd;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have assigned CSS style only for the input fields and for select.
The combo-box uses select tag and hence you need to define style for select tag as well.

Defining style for select:disabled should give you the expected result.

```
input:disabled, select:disabled {
    background:#dddddd;
}
```

Here is a short example demonstrating the same on jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/SZz4F/